# redirect to another page on click of submit button using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

using Backbone.js after calling `collection.create()` i want to redirect my page to the link which is having currently added record's unique id. this link(means link on which my page is redirected) should also pass to `Backbone.sync`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (which is not easy), it seems to me you could mean something like adding

```
document.location.replace(<model>.id)
```

into your models initialize function. However, I dont understand what you mean by "this link should also pass to Backbone.sync. Please clarify your question (and work on your accept rate)

Comment: I still dont understand what you mean by "the link should pass to BAckbone.sync". Should the link be passed to Backbone.sync as an argument? If that is what you mean: it already is passed indirectly via the unique id in the models.